# WP text editor меняет html разметку

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

Я использую такую разметку:

```
<div class="owl-carousel-wrap photo-gallery ">
  <div id="photoGallery" class="owl-carousel ">
    <a href="#galleryPhotos"  data-slide-to="0"><div class="item " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#photoGalleryModal">
  <div class="photo-gallery_item"><img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-479" src="http://site/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/slide_6-comp-1024x683.jpg" alt="" /></div></div></a>
  <a href="#galleryPhotos"  data-slide-to="1"><div class="item " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#photoGalleryModal">
 <div class="photo-gallery_item"><img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-480" src="http://site/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/slide_7-comp-1024x683.jpg" alt="" /></div></div></a>
 <div>
 </div>
```

Когда я вставляю эту разметку в текстовый редактор, удаляются теги `a`, и получается это:

```
<div class="owl-carousel-wrap photo-gallery ">
    <div id="photoGallery" class="owl-carousel ">
  <div class="item " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#photoGalleryModal">
   <div class="photo-gallery_item"><img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-479" src="http://site/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/slide_6-comp-1024x683.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</div>
  <div class="item " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#photoGalleryModal">
   <div class="photo-gallery_item"><img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-480" src="http://site/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/slide_7-comp-1024x683.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

Подключила плагин `TinyMCE Advanced`, но это не помогло. Сейчас не использую плагины для редактирования кода.

Как отменить удаление тегов?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете TinyMCE то у него есть параметр [valid_elements](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_elements)  и в нём нужно указать чтобы он не урезал тег `a`, к примеру вот так:

```
valid_elements: a
```

Но раз вы через редактор редактируете исходный код я бы советовал полностью все теги разрешить:

```
valid_elements : '*[*]'
```

Comment: а где это указать? в functions.php?

Comment: @MarinaVoronova смотря как у вас подключается редактор, если как плагин ищите в настройках плагина

Comment: зашла в настройки, открыла код плагина, но там нет таких строк, и вообще не нашла места куда эту строку добавить.

Comment: @MarinaVoronova смотрите в описании плагина или его документации, где то должна быть возможность добавлять опции при ините плагина, я с этим плагином не работал, только на прямую, так что как это настроить в плагиине не подскажу.

Answer (score 0):

Если кто-то ещё при поиске ответа попадет сюда - вот полный ответ.
Благодарю @YaroslavMolchan за то, что натолкнул на решение данной проблемы.

Для того, чтобы оключить урезание тегов TinyMCE, нужно найти файл **class-wp-editor.php**, который находится в папке **wp-includes**.

В этом файле находим массив (в моей версии WP он начинался на 658 строке):

```
$mceInit = array (
    'selector' => "#$editor_id",
    'wpautop' => (bool) $set['wpautop'],
    'indent' => ! $set['wpautop'],
    'toolbar1' => implode( ',', $mce_buttons ),
    'toolbar2' => implode( ',', $mce_buttons_2 ),
    'toolbar3' => implode( ',', $mce_buttons_3 ),
    'toolbar4' => implode( ',', $mce_buttons_4 ),
    'tabfocus_elements' => $set['tabfocus_elements'],
    'body_class' => $body_class
);
```

Вот сюда и стоит добавить параметр **valid_elements**. В моем случае мне нужно было разрешить се элементы, поэтому итоговый результат был такой:

```
$mceInit = array (
    'selector' => "#$editor_id",
    'wpautop' => (bool) $set['wpautop'],
    'indent' => ! $set['wpautop'],
    'toolbar1' => implode( ',', $mce_buttons ),
    'toolbar2' => implode( ',', $mce_buttons_2 ),
    'toolbar3' => implode( ',', $mce_buttons_3 ),
    'toolbar4' => implode( ',', $mce_buttons_4 ),
    'tabfocus_elements' => $set['tabfocus_elements'],
    'body_class' => $body_class,
    'valid_elements' => '*[*]'
);
```